A little emoji puzzle
Can you please fill in the ? correctly and of course justify it?:


The question mark should be replaced by...

 ...two bows.

Because what we have here is...

 ...the lyrics to the last line of the children's song "Head, Shoulders, Knees and Toes" where all the body parts are instead represented by emojis for rhyming words.

So we have:

 "and ties and tears and south and bows; bed, boulders, bees and bows (bees and bows)"

 instead of:

 "and eyes and ears and mouth and nose; head, shoulders, knees and toes (knees and toes)"

All together now...!

Ok that was solved a lot faster than I had anticipated

@PDT Hehe, I was looking at the last line and saying to myself rot13("orq, ebpxf, orrf naq objf"), when I wondered if there was a synonym for the second that began with the same letter as the others. As soon as I found that and said it out loud, I knew what I was dealing with here! A nice little teaser, thanks :)
